Bare copper wire as a fuse
Consider building a fuse using bare copper wire, so as to melt fast at 60 A.
What would be the cross section area of this wire?
(I tried searching online for tables, but the results were confusing and hard to find; unlike tinned copper fuse wire. I have also seen the similar question What size of copper wire can act as a 150 A fuse? but that question is much more complicated and the use-case idiosyncratic.)
Use case: I seem to have .1mm diameter (seemingly) cu wire from ages past, which I am considering using.

The answers in What size of copper wire can act as a 150 A fuse? suggest this is not a good idea.

If this is a theory question or just and experiment, it's interesting but underspecified: how quickly is "fast"?, does the tinning make much difference?.  If it's something you wanted to use in a live circuit, it's dangerous: basically it's tricky to make a fuse blow reliably at some specific time-current point.  If you are trying to protect some cabling or circuit choose an industrial one made for the purpose.

Copper melts at more than 1000 degrees C. That's a light yellow incandescent temperature- enough to ignite things  some distance away from radiation. That also probably means that the makeshift fuse will have to drop more voltage than a well-designed one.

There won't be much difference between tinned copper wire and plain copper. The tinning is to stop the copper tarnishing.
Fuses aren't fast or precise. If you want something that will pass 50A, then it won't blow fast above 60A.
If you use the charts to find a 60A fuse, then it will pass 60A forever. It may take minutes or hours to blow at 80A, and probably won't even blow fast at 100A.

Fuses can be quite fast and very precise. But that will be a manufactured fuse in a reasonably controlled environment, not bare wire.
